# Fuse for a heating element

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, heat, fuses

I am designing PCB for a heating control system. I have planned to use PCB mountable SSR for the control the heater element. The SSR can handle maximum of 2A current and heating element not exceed that current.

Anyway, I decided to add a fuse between SSR and heater element. This fuse insert to a PCB mountable fuse holder.

Is their any special fuse for heating element? Can I use normal 2A glass fuse for my application?

[image: PCB mountable fuse holder]

Comment: @jsotola I want to protect SSR if heater element get more current than 2A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't use a standard fuses, they are too slow to preserve the SSR.
Happy days: [fast fuses do exist](http://www.crydom.com/en/tech/newsletters/solid%20statements%20-%20protecting%20ssrs%20against%20short%20circuit%20and%20overcurrent.pdf)!

Comment: Thanks @theGarz. can you command a suitable fuse for my application?My SSR has 4A^2s Output I^2t value.